# Language level above fluent, but not native?

Tags: resume, skills

How, on a resume, should I describe language level which is above what's commonly described as fluent, but it's not my native language?

It's a language I speak at home, and have been doing so for 10 years.

Comment: @jcmeloni: not a duplicate, I've already look at it before posting question and it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: That's why it says "possible" duplicate. :)  FWIW, if I were to answer this question in a general (e.g. not localized) way, my answer wouldn't be any different than my answer on the other one.

Comment: What is above fluent?

Comment: In other words, as a native English speaker, I would describe my proficiency in English as fluent.

Comment: @thursdaysgeek: *"fluent"*  means that a person speaks without pausing, but doesn't say much about how broad their vocabulary is or how often do they make grammatical mistakes. And as per most resumes, people describing themselves as *"fluent"* in given language very often don't speak it very well.

Comment: @scaaahu: except I didn't speak it as a child. By family in this case I mean my wife and children,  not my parents.

Comment: @scaaahu: read the question

Comment: Hi Vartec, I'm voting to close this as a duplicate to the linked question because I agree that the answer to this question can be found in there. "Fluent" is really the highest level that I know of for a language, and I would expect it to mean the person speaks the language as well as a native speaker, with the possible exception of some slang terms. If there is a term used for beyond fluent, I've never heard of it, and think that question would be more appropriate for [English.SE](http://english.stackexchange.com/) than on The Workplace

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I consider "fluent" to be the top, and anything else to be "not fluent". I would caution against being too accurate/cute.

That said, something like "expert" might be unambiguous enough or "bi-lingual in X and Y" as being a clear indication that you are equally awesome at both.

Comment: +1 for "bi-lingual". That's a good way of putting it if "fluent" is being misused a lot in your area of the world.

Comment: Fair enough. The reason I had doubt about *fluent* is that it's abused by people who's level I'd describe as barely communicative.